# Not able to send data on reply channel using tcp-outbound-gateway with ActiveMQ

Tags: tcp, spring-integration, activemq-classic

My Requirement is to get data from TCP, after getting the data from TCP convert into java object and send on ActiveMQ. Post that after doing some processing need to send the acknowledgement/response code on same channel on TCP.
To fulfill this requirement I am using tcp-outbound-gateway as bidirectional communication is required.

Problem is I am not able to send acknowledgement with ActiveMQ. If I comment out ActiveMQ part and write a dummy string on replyChannel it is visible, but the moment I send the object on Active MQ queue it is giving me a message **"null reply received for  nothing to send"**.

I am using a new queue to get the acknowledgement and trying to put the response on reply channel of tcp-outbound-gate, but error message is ***no output-channel or replyChannel header available.***

I got the MessageHeaders details via Incoming message and sending it via queue to use copyHeader. I am able to set the headers and see paylod in Message object, verified the same by applying Interceptos on reply channel, but still getting the same error ***no output-channel or replyChannel header available.***

Code is :

```
<int:gateway id="gw" default-reply-channel="replyChannel" default-reply-timeout="10000" service-interface= "com.telnet.core.integration.connection.ParseTcpConfiguration$SimpleGateway"
default-request-channel="${server.inboundChannel}"/>

<int:channel id="telnetLandingChannel" />

<ip:tcp-connection-factory id="serverFactory" type="server"  host="${server.host}" port="${server.port}" single-use="false"
serializer="${server.serializer}" deserializer="${server.serializer}" task-executor="serverFactoryTaskExecutor"/>

<ip:tcp-inbound-gateway id="serverInboundAdpater"   request-channel="telnetLandingChannel"  reply-channel="replyChannel"
connection-factory="serverFactory"  error-channel="errorChannel"    reply-timeout="1000000" auto-startup="false"/>    

<int:channel id="replyChannel"></int:channel>

<beans:bean id="acknowledgementHandler"     class= "com.telnet.core.integration.AcknowledgementHandler">
</beans:bean>

<int:channel id="incidentDispatchMessageChannel" datatype="${incident.interaction.dispatch.response.datatype}"></int:channel>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="incidentDispatchMessageChannelAdapter" error-channel="errorChannel"
connection-factory="mqConnectionFactory"
destination-name="${incident.processing.tcp.dispatch.response.queues}" 
channel="incidentDispatchMessageChannel"/>

<int:transformer id="incidentMessageActivator" 
input-channel="incidentDispatchMessageChannel" 
output-channel="replyChannel"
ref="acknowledgementHandler" method="incidentAck">
</int:transformer>
```

---

```
public Message incidentAck(final DefaultIncidentAcknowledgeMessage defaultIncidentAcknowledgeMessage){

    MessageHeaders ms = (MessageHeaders)defaultIncidentAcknowledgeMessage.getProperties().get("MessageHeader");
    Message<String> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload("1").copyHeaders(ms).build();
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to see your Integration configuration though, but let me guess that you are loosing `TemporaryReplyChannel` object in the `replyChannel` header because it isn't `Serializable`. Consider to use:

```
<int:header-enricher>
    <int:header-channels-to-string/>
</int:header-enricher>
```

somewhere before sending to the ActveMQ.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#header-channel-registry) for more information.

**UPDATE**

Looks like this is a continuation of [Receive the acknowledgement from TCP server to our application using spring Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587195/receive-the-acknowledgement-from-tcp-server-to-our-application-using-spring-inte). And I see you still use the same `replyChannel` for many places. That isn't going to work properly. The `replyChannel` header from the gateway can accept only one reply. Even if we figure out what to do with the reply from ActiveMQ, the `TemporaryReplyChannel` will be fulfilled with the reply from the TCP Outbound Gateway.

If I understand you correctly, alongside with the reply from the TCP you need also get some message from ActiveMQ. And send everything as a reply to the gateway call. For this purpose I suggest you to consider to use Aggregator and figure out some custom correlation strategy to match the reply from TCP to that acknowledge from the ActiveMQ. After aggregation you really can just use the existing `replyChannel` header to reply to the gateway.

Comment: On which Channel I need to use header-enricher

Comment: I am able to see the acknowledgement if message is not send on ActiceMQ. Looks like some how gateway is not able to get any reply on reply channel or channel is closed. Is there any different way to handle reply which needs to be send on gateway, in case of Active MQ. As now due to Active MQ now it is not a synchronous call.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer

Comment: I have used changes the channel name and post that added Inbound adapter and Outbound adapter with existing code instead of Inbound Gateway and it worked fine.

Comment: As my code call is asynchronous probability that's why i was not able to get reply using replyChannel of Gateway. I am not much aware about asynchronous gateway as normally it works in synchronous fashion, how to use it in asynchronous mode.

Comment: Please, raise a new SO question. I'm somehow loosing context to understand you